# Merging two database in pyrocms

Tags: xampp, pyrocms

I am currently doing a project with 2 team members on pyrocms. We all team member made dynamic pages.In pyrocms the dynamic pages all are saved in the database. NOw the problem is how we gonna merge our 2 databases !!

Comment: What version of PyroCMS is used?

Comment: I am using PyroCMS v2.2 @JahandidehAR

Comment: That won't be an easy job to get done, because in pyro 2.2 pages use streams, any custom field and data stored in them at your pages or custom layouts are stored separately and they pass ids to group up together. I suggest open up admin pannel for one of them and just make/copy new `page layouts` and `custom fields` and `page contents` ... to the other one. I know this is not the answer you were searching for.